# Access: Delete Query asks for a parameter

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-delete

I try to run the following DELETE query:

```
DELETE T_PROPOS.*, T_PROPOS.Projekt, T_PROPOS.[PSP-Element], T_PROPOS.Typ, T_PROPOS.Jahr, T_PROPOS.Wert, T_PROPOS.Datum
FROM T_PROPOS
WHERE NOT (((T_PROPOS.Projekt)=[T_PROPOS_Ohne_Duplikate].[Projekt]) AND ((T_PROPOS.[PSP-Element])=[T_PROPOS_Ohne_Duplikate].[PSP-Element]) AND ((T_PROPOS.Typ)=[T_PROPOS_Duplikate_löschen].[Typ]) AND ((T_PROPOS.Jahr)=[T_PROPOS_Duplikate_löschen].[Jahr]) AND ((T_PROPOS.Wert)=[T_PROPOS_Duplikate_löschen].[Wert]) AND ((T_PROPOS.Datum)=[T_PROPOS_Duplikate_löschen].[Datum]));
```

But when I run the query Access asks me for the parameters of every condition. So I need to give values to `[T_PROPOS_Ohne_Duplikate].[Projekt]` etc. But I want to delete all rows from `T_PROPOS` which are not in `T_PROPOS_Ohne_Duplikate`. How can I make Access compare the two tables?

Comment: Well, `[T_PROPOS_Ohne_Duplikate]` is not defined in your `WHERE` clause.  That confuses me and no doubt MS Access as well.

Comment: Do you know how I can define that in my WHERE clause?

Comment: How is `T_PROPOS_Duplikate_löschen` involved?  You don't mention that table in your description, yet it appears multiple times in the WHERE clause.  Were those really supposed to be `T_PROPOS_Ohne_Duplikate`?

Answer (score 0):

Use this below simple query. Not sure if it works in Access.

```
delete from T_PROPOS where Projekt not in 
(select Projekt from T_PROPOS_Ohne_Duplikate);
```

Comment: Thanks, I already tried NOT IN (and that works), but it takes too much time for my query.

Comment: You can filer using any date condition or create an index on the column Projekt which makes it faster

Answer (score 0):

Since you refer to columns from two unreferenced tables, consider two `NOT EXISTS` clauses. Also `DELETE * FROM` is equivalent to `DELETE FROM` in MS Access.

```
DELETE
FROM T_PROPOS main
WHERE NOT EXISTS
   (SELECT 1 FROM [T_PROPOS_Ohne_Duplikate] o_dup
    WHERE main.Projekt = o_dup.[Projekt]
      AND main.[PSP-Element] = o_dup.[PSP-Element])

  AND NOT EXISTS    
   (SELECT 1 FROM [T_PROPOS_Duplikate_löschen] l_dup
    WHERE main.Typ = l_dup.[Typ]
      AND main.Jahr = l_dup.[Jahr]
      AND main.Wert = l_dup.[Wert]
      AND main.Datum = l_dup.[Datum]);
```